# How to create a 3 positions toggle?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, toggle

I would like to create a 3 positions (or more) toggle on a web form to replace radio buttons. Something like this:

[image: 3 positions toggle]

The selected value should be of a different color than the non-selected ones and only one value can be selected. How would you go about this? How would you get the selected value from the form?

Comment: Take a look at http://code.stephenmorley.org/html-and-css/styling-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/#imageBased. Google __styling radio buttons__ for more sites with examples.

Comment: @Barmar they look good but not really what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: How about the jQuery UI Button widget: https://jqueryui.com/button/#radio. That demo looks exactly like what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link provided in comments explains it all, basicly it works with `:checked + label` and absolute position for `input`.

```css
/* styling*/
.optionlabel {
  display:table;
  border-collapse:collapse;
  border:1px solid lightblue;
}
.optionlabel [type="radio"] {
  position:absolute;
  left:-9999px
}
.optionlabel label {
  display:table-cell;
  width:100px;
  height:50px;
  border-left:inherit;
  text-align:center;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
/* your magic ? */
:checked + label {background:#7ED321;}
```

```html
<p class="optionlabel">
<input id="option1" type="radio" name="option"/><label for="option1">Option 1</label>
<input id="option2" type="radio" name="option"/><label for="option2">Option 2</label>
<input id="option3" type="radio" name="option"/><label for="option3">Option 3</label>
</p>
```

*(next time if you provide your html/bootstrapped we use it to demonstrate)*